# JSXGraph - intersections and polygons created from points of intersections

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I am new to jsxgraph, also not so proficient in js, I hope you could point me in right direction with my problem.

I'm trying to:
1) create intersections of lines that go through a rectangle (there will be a large number of these lines),
2) file the space between them with polygons of different colors.

Here is how the whole piece of code (for some reason the jsfiddle doesn't want to work! :/):
https://jsfiddle.net/czarrna/me55dw4h/4/

My code does not work unfortunatelly :/

```js
var typical_mn = board.create('polygon', [t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4], {
  fillColor: '#ff9600',
  withLines: false
});

var p1_1 = board.create('intersection', [l_20, typical_mn, 0], {
  visible: true
});
var p1_2 = board.create('intersection', [l_20, typical_mn, 1], {
  visible: true
});

var p2_1 = board.create('intersection', [l_30, typical_mn, 0], {
  visible: true
});
var p2_2 = board.create('intersection', [l_30, typical_mn, 1], {
  visible: true
});

var p3_1 = board.create('intersection', [l_40, typical_mn, 0], {
  visible: true
});
var p3_2 = board.create('intersection', [l_40, typical_mn, 1], {
  visible: true
});

var pol_20_30 = board.create('polygon', [p1_1, p1_2, p2_1, p2_1], {
  fillColor: '#555',
  withLines: false
});

var pol_30_40 = board.create('polygon', [p2_1, p2_1, p3_1, p3_2], {
  fillColor: '#333',
  withLines: false
});
```

```html
<script src="http://czarrna.kei.pl/jsxgraph/src/loadjsxgraph.js"></script>
<script src="http://czarrna.kei.pl/jsxgraph/distrib/jsxgraph.css"></script>
<div id="jxgbox" class="jxgbox" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I hope someone could help me with this please! Would be grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, external libraries in jsfiddle have to be included with https. JSXGraph is available with https for example at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsxgraph/0.99.3/jsxgraphcore.js .

At the moment, there is no intersection algorithm between polygons and lines. But one can intersect the polygon borders with lines. For this, the `withLines` property of the polygon has to be set to `true`. Then the borders can be accessed with the `borders` array.

In your example it would look like

```
var typical_mn = board.create('polygon',[t_1,t_2,t_3, t_4], {fillColor:'#ff9600', withLines:true});

in_20 = board.create('intersection', [l_20, typical_mn.borders[0]],{visible:true});
in_30 = board.create('intersection', [l_30, typical_mn.borders[0]],{visible:true});
in_40 = board.create('intersection', [l_40, typical_mn.borders[0]],{visible:true});
```

Intersection between lines and polygons is an interesting features, I will create a ticket on github.

Comment: Alfred,
Thank you very much for your answer. It helps me a lot.